# How to get select field in model using laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, model, laravel-models

I want to fetch only the specific column seller_db from seller table with the help of model, but when i used this below code my relationship shows null value, please help me to find my mistake, and how can i fetch selected one field with model using laravel?

here is my User.php file.

User.php

```
    public function sellerDB()
        {
            $instance = $this->hasOne('\App\Seller', 'user_id', 'id')->select('seller_db');
            return $instance;
        }
```

Comment: you should be selecting the 'id' and any foreign keys needed for the relationship

Comment: @lagbox i already mentioned this, user_id is my foreign key, and id is my primary key.

Comment: then you need to select the `user_id` field at least

Comment: Look up “custom get attributes from laravel model”

Comment: what problem are you trying to solve at the moment? as this relationshp should just return the relationship and something else should specify if it wants to load all the fields or not

Comment: @ParteekKumar you can check my answer newly

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** I made a mistake, I misunderstood your database design, it's necessary add an aditional method to resolve this:

```
    public function seller()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('\App\Seller', 'user_id', 'id')
    }

    public function sellerDB()
    {
        return $this->seller->seller_db;
    }
```

In this case you can call $user->sellerDB() and receive the column seller_db